# Wifi Realtek not working on debian bookworm

Tags: debian, wifi-driver

I installed Debian 12.04 on my laptop unfortunately the wifi is not working. I can enter my hotspot password, but the wifi never connect in the end.
My wifi network card is:

```
# lspci | grep -i wireless
02.00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

The kernel driver in use is

```
# lspci -vv -s 02.00.0 | 'driver in use'
Kernel driver in use: rtw_8821ce
```

it's strange it does not work at first install. It worked previously on Ubuntu.
do you have any idea?

Comment: anything show in `dmesg` regarding firmware for that device?

Comment: Drivers for that card may need to be installed into the kernel: see https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=151517 and https://miloserdov.org/?p=5930